# DOM Input elements should have autocomplete attributes

Tags: codeigniter-3

> I have eror verbose

```
[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"): (More info: https://#) <input type=​"password" name=​"password" id=​"password" class=​"abs-form mtb-10" placeholder=​"Password" required>​
```

What the mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"autocomplete" determines what, if any, permission the browser has to provide automated help suggesting form field values. It also lets the browser know the type of information expected in the field.

For a password field, I would suggest `autocomplete="off"`.

Give that a try and see if the verifier changes its mind. The other option would be to try `autocomplete="current-password"`

Complete details on "autocomplete" attribute [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete).